# Insert 100 incremented rows into mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert 100 rows into a mysql table.
The table looks like:

```
+--------+--------+---------+-------------+
| idselo | codigo | saqueta | equipamento |
+--------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

idselo is auto-incremented. saqueta and equipamento have the same value for all 100 rows. codigo is the column that I want to increment and goes from 0 to 100 with an offset. Per example, if it starts at 222, I'll insert the values 222-321.

I know how to do that on php and send all the data to mysql, but isn't better to do that loop on mysql?

Thank you

Comment: MySQL can handle thousands of queries per second. Using a PHP loop for "just" 100 isn't that heavy.

Comment: If `idselo` is already auto-incremented, can you not just add the offset to it? Why do you need a separate column?

Comment: 100 records usually takes less than 1 second to store on the database.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why but I was thinking that I'll need to send all the data from client to server, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

this is easiest single query:

```
$query = "Insert INTO table (codigo, saqueta , equipamento) VALUES ";
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
    if($i!=1) $query .= ",";
    $query .= "($i, 'your data for saqueta' , 'your data for equipamento')";
}
$query .= ";";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select null as idselo, @row := @row + 1 as codigo, 'X' as saqueta, 'Y' as equipamento
from (select @row := 221) t, t, t t2, t t3, t t4, t t5, t t6, t t7 
where @row < 222 + 99;
```